# awk check based on start and end range:

Tags: awk

Would like to extract all the lines from first file, if the first file first field is falls within a range of 
Second file third field (Start Range) and fourth field (End Range)

Have tried the below command  and incomplete , please help

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{ start[$1] = $3; end[$1] = $4; next } ( ($1 >= start[$1]) && ($1 <= end[$1]) )' f22.txt f11.txt
```

*f11.txt*:

```
12,abc,ppp
15,def,ppp
20,xyz,ppp
6,hij,ppp
8,mno,ppp
```

*f22.txt*

```
Data1,Data2,Start,End
qqq,www,1,5
qqq,www,10,15
qqq,www,7,9
```

*Desired Output:*

```
12,abc,ppp
15,def,ppp
8,mno,ppp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line should do the job:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{s[NR]=$3;e[NR]=$4;n++;next}
     {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)if($1>=s[i]&&$1<=e[i]){print;break}}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is working fine , how to print the match field as well from file 2 like output         12,abc,ppp,qqq,www,10,15
15,def,ppp,qqq,www,10,15
8,mno,ppp,qqq,www,7,9

Comment: @user3350223 then you can save the line in file2 in another array `c[NR]=$0`, when you print, do `print; print c[i];break`

Comment: sorry to disturb again, OP format is not in order , tried the command awk -F, 'NR==FNR{s[NR]=$3;e[NR]=$4;c[NR]=$0;n++;next} {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)if($1>=s[i]&&$1<=e[i]){print; print c[i];break}}'
Got op like this
(1st line) 12,abc,ppp
(2nd line) qqq,www,10,15
(3rd line) 15,def,ppp
(4th line) qqq,www,10,15
(5th line) 8,mno,ppp
(6th line) qqq,www,7,9

where as expecting to print 
 
(firstline:) 12,abc,ppp,qqq,www,10,15
(secondline:) 15,def,ppp,qqq,www,10,15
(third line :) 8,mno,ppp,qqq,www,7,9

Comment: @user3350223 it will follow the order of your file1. if you want other order, try `sort` or other solution.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` with `grep`:

```
awk -F, '{for (i = $3; i <= $4; i++) {print "^"i","}}' input2 | grep -f - input1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working fine , please provide some explanation to undersatnd your command ..